# Is there an elegant way to initialize and return value of nullable field using Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a piece of code which returns value of one field, but also initializes it:

```
public Observable<Integer> asObservable() {
    if (subject == null) {
        subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0);
    }
    return subject;
}
```

I'm trying to use `Optional` class to avoid `if` statement:

```
public Observable<Integer> asObservableWithOptional() {
    Optional.ofNullable(subject)
            .executeIfAbsent(() -> BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0));
    return subject;
}
```

Hovewer I'm still not happy with this code. Is there a way to turn this methos into one with one statement only? Something similar to following won't work because `subject` have not been initialized during call to `ofNullable` factory method:

```
    return Optional.ofNullable(subject)
            .executeIfAbsent(() -> BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0))
            .get();
```

Note: I'm not using original Java8 API, but aNNiMON port of this API https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API.

Comment: Java 8's `Optional` class does not have a method `executeIfAbsent`. Are you using a different `Optional` instead?

Comment: generally what you are trying to do is called `memoization` and you could use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331327/does-java-8-have-cached-support-for-suppliers

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API. It is a port of `Stream` and `Optional` API for Java7. I didn't knew it differs from Java8 API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
return subject = Optional.ofNullable(subject).orElseGet(() -> BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0));
```

of course, you can use a ternary conditional operator instead of creating an `Optional` just to discard it immediately:

```
return subject != null ? subject : (subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like this :

```
return (subject == null ? (subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0)) : subject);
```

Comment: But this solution does not change the state of `subject` variable.

Comment: Hello, Aleksander, thanks for pointing out. I have edited the answer, azro also pointed the same.